# Can you remove a relative adverb before an adverb clause?

Tags: grammar, dependent-clause

Is the following sentence correct?

> Paul felt like he was the happiest man on earth, founding his own distillery.

Don't you need something else besides just a comma between *earth* and *founding*?

Is "founding his own distillery" an adverb clause with its relative adverb *when* unexpressed? And if so, is the comma needed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108096/discussion-on-question-by-dontknowwhatimdoing-can-you-remove-a-relative-adverb).